POST 502 Gateway error - Plugin keeps loading
Within the WordPress website there is the plugin Easy Appointments. This plugin always worked but since a couple of weeks to a month the pages of the plugin keep loading.
When looking at the back-end (console log) there is a error which probably causes this. It is the POST (link to website and link to .php) 502 (Bad Gateway) and especially it is within this part of the code:
                    try {
                        **r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null)**
                    } 


I have tried changing the back-end but that doesn`t work. Can you guys see where somethings went wrong?

I have tried looking within the back-end for why this error accures but nothing changed within the code for the past years so I don`t know why this happens.

I have tried some resolutions of other Stack Overflow questions but those didn`t work.


If you need more information regarding this problem, please let me know and I will share it.
Thank you in advance

502 Bad Gateway is usually what you get when there is more than one server involved (one used to proxy requests to another), and the communication between the two runs into some error. Is that the case in your setup here? If you are not sure, then also check with your hoster.

@CBroe Thanks for the response. No, not that I know off. A new website has been launched (more modern one) but it is on another domain and not Wordpress so I cannot see that being the problem.
